# dynamic action not firing in production environment

Tags: apex

My first application was developed in apex 4.2 when apex 5.1 had been released I created a new application and copied pages from the previous application which was apex 4.2.

I am currently using that application which being upgraded to the last version apex 21.1.

I add dynamic action in an interactive grid column, it works fine in the development environment. if I used the application in the production environment the dynamic action not firing at all.

if I created a new application and add the dynamic action everything works fine in the development or production.

My application is hosted at a company hosting apex.

Answer (score 0):

I found an error in javascript in the page through tracing error via chrome console. I create a new page instead of the old one. dynamic action now works fine.